# Importing data from another activity, Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, input

This is my main class. Where I receive doubles from users input.

```
public void onPayClick(View view){
    Intent payIntent = new Intent(this, payActivity.class);

    final EditText amountInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountInput);
    final EditText yearInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yearInput);
    final EditText interestInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.interestInput);

    double amountDouble = Double.parseDouble(amountInput.getText().toString());
    double yearDouble = Double.parseDouble(yearInput.getText().toString());
    double interestDouble = Double.parseDouble(interestInput.getText().toString());

    payIntent.putExtra("amountDouble", amountDouble);
    payIntent.putExtra("yearDouble", yearDouble);
    payIntent.putExtra("interestDouble", interestDouble);

    startActivity(payIntent);
}
```

This is my second activity, here I would like to calculate the loan but I'm just trying to print amountDouble to see if it works, which it doesn't....

```
TextView printPay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printPay);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay);

    Bundle payData = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(payData == null){
        printPay.setText("Villa, þú verður að filla upp í alla reiti.");
        return;
    }
    String amountDouble = payData.getString("amountDouble");
    String yearDouble = payData.getString("yearDouble");
    String interestDouble = payData.getString("interestDouble");

    String sum1 = amountDouble;
    printPay.setText(sum1);
}
```

Each time I click payButton the application crashes.

Comment: where you defined your TextView printPay in second activity ?

Comment: You must do that after setContentView in onCreate.

Comment: `TextView printPay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printPay);` Define in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 1st `Activity` you are adding those values in `intent` directly so you have to fetch those data from `intent` not from `bundle`. Besides that you are declaring that `TextView` at the top of your class so it will be *null* define it inside `onCreate(...)` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay);`. In 2nd `Activity` change like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay);
    TextView printPay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printPay);

    String amountDouble = String.valueOf(getIntent().getDoubleExtra("amountDouble", 0.0));
    String yearDouble = String.valueOf(getIntent().getDoubleExtra("yearDouble", 0.0);
    String interestDouble = String.valueOf(getIntent().getDoubleExtra("interestDouble", 0.0);

    String sum1 = amountDouble;
    printPay.setText(sum1);
}
```

[more info of getDoubleExtra(java.lang.String, double)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getDoubleExtra(java.lang.String,%20double))

Comment: The problem was the TextView. Thanks alot!